# how to store into a session and display current users information

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

```
public class UserDA
{
    private static string _connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["airmazin"].ConnectionString;

    //update,delete,insert,getuser

    public static void UserInsert(User user)
    {

        string queryStr = "INSERT INTO Account (username, gender, email, password) values (@username, @gender, @email, @password);";

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_connStr);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(queryStr, conn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", user.userName);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", user.gender);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", user.email);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", user.password);
         
        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();

    }

    protected void btn_Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string userName = tb_userName.Text;
        string gender = rbl_gender.SelectedValue.ToString();
        string email = tb_email.Text;
        string password = tb_password.Text;
        User user = new User(userName, gender, email, password);
        UserDA.UserInsert(user);

    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void btn_Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //if (txt_userEmail == null) { }
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["airmazin"].ToString());
        con.Open(); 
        string query = "select count   from Account where email='" + txt_userEmail.Text+ "' and password='" + txt_userPass.Text +"'" ;

       SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        string output = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        con.Close();
        if (output == "1")
        {
            // Create a session
            Session["Account"] = txt_userEmail.Text;
        
            
            Response.Redirect("User_Profile.aspx");

       }

       else
        {
            Response.Write("<script>alert('Login NOT successful');</script>");
        }
    }

    protected void btn_loginSignup_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("SignUp.aspx");
    }
}
```

I have inserted data into the data base and how do I store it into a session and display the current users information(Eg: Username, email, gender etc) on my profile page.

Comment: Do not do `select count` because it will give you the number of records. Get the actual info you need and then store it in the session.

Comment: i used select count * . i am getting the information because i logged in thats why i have to check for the username and password using the database @CodingYoshi

Comment: Run the query `select count * ` using management studio or another tool and see what you get. `select count *` will not work because it Has syntax error. `select count(*)` will work but that will return a number. You need to get username, email, name etc (whatever you need) so use `select username, email...`

Answer (score 0):

1. You can access the session value in aspx by <%=Session["Account"]%>
2. You should wrap the SqlConnection in a using statement, otherwise, you connection is not released when exception.

   using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) 
   {
    //your code
   }